# Closing a useEffect Memory Leak in React-Native

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks, react-hooks, use-effect

When navigating from one set of maps in my expo app to another, I often get this error if I navigate before the maps are done loading:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it  indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous  tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function

How do I plug this memory leak?

Below is my code:

```js
function MapsScreen({navigation}) { 

const [user_latitude, setUserLatitude] = useState(0)
const [user_longitude, setUserLongitude] = useState(0)
const [position_error, setPositionError] = useState(null)
   
useEffect(() => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => { 
    setUserLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
    setUserLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
    setPositionError(null);
  }, 

  error => setPositionError(error.message),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 2000}
  ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Waheed answer,
btw it is more easier if you already have react-navigation v5.x in your code ,
it's simple just use `useFocusEffect` method, the function executed when screen is focused only. I give example with the addition of second check using `isActive` flag checker.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'

function MapsScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [user_latitude, setUserLatitude] = useState(0)
  const [user_longitude, setUserLongitude] = useState(0)
  const [position_error, setPositionError] = useState(null)

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      let isActive = true

      const fetchGeoPositon = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            if (isActive) {
              setUserLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
              setUserLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
              setPositionError(null)
            }
          },

          error => isActive && setPositionError(error.message),
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 2000 }
        )
      }

      fetchGeoPositon()

      return () => {
        isActive = false
      }
    }, [])
  )
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Comment: What is the difference between useEffect and useFocusEffect?

Comment: I am working with RN version 5. Will it make mounting/unmounting more efficient?

Comment: @MK_Pierce, yes i have tried it on my current Project. useFocusEffect works well. It really listens mounted and Unmounted screen behavior compared to useEffect.

Comment: useEffect is an effect Hooks from React itself. For easy to understand, useEffect from react is something like componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

useFocusEffect in other hand, it is comes from React-Navigation package, not from React.  It run side-effects when screen is Focused or Blur.

Comment: Or, you can also use  ` useIsFocused ` from react-navigation, it is something like, simple hook to get focus status of the screen.
-> import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'

you can read more here bro : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/

Comment: useFocusEffect remedied my issues. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**
`You will get this warning when your component is unmounted from the memory and some async task is in the process like you make a network call and tries to leave the screen before resolving the promise.`

**Solution**: `To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

**A solution to your problem**: As looking at your code you are changing your state when the component tries to unmount, You have to use the cleanup function with the `useEffect` hook, add a flag before `setUserLatitude`, `setUserLongitude`, `setPositionError` to make sure that the component is not unmounted from the memory

```
function MapsScreen({navigation}) { 

const [user_latitude, setUserLatitude] = useState(0)
const [user_longitude, setUserLongitude] = useState(0)
const [position_error, setPositionError] = useState(null)
   
useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true // Add this 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => { 
   if(mounted){ // Add this
    setUserLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
    setUserLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
    setPositionError(null);
    }
  }, 

  error => setPositionError(error.message),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 2000}
  ); 

 return () => {
  mounted = false // add this
 }
}, []);
```

Read more about it [Clean up function](https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm)

Comment: That's all that is necessary?

Comment: Not all but you need to have a clean up function to remove this warning.

Comment: How much more code do you think is necessary to make it work?

Comment: this one ```return () => {
  console.log("cleaned up"); // add this clean up function
 }```

Comment: Added. Anything else in particular?

Comment: these braces in the arugment ```[]```

Comment: Added as well. I added the recommendations you suggested above to the code and am still getting a memory leak error.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a few more code with the comment `add this` you can try with that.

Comment: If this was Reddit I would give you gold. Thank you so much!

Comment: Waheed, your solution worked for a little while, but the component will no longer unMount when I leave the page, so this will prevent the next component from loading and mounting.  

Do you know of a way to fix this?